# Values of checked and unchecked checkbox passed to Django view

Tags: html, django, ajax

I have a checkbox that I would like it to return different values when check/unchecked.

```
<form id="cat">{% csrf_token %} 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="1" unchecked> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('submit','#cat',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/cat',
        data:{
            chk:$('#chk').val(), 
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
```

In the `cat` function in `views.py`, I have

```
chked=request.POST.get('chk', '')
```

I want to assign `chked` with different values with the checkbox checked/unchecked.

I was referring to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox and thought that value would be different if checked or not.

However, same value of 1 returned whether checked or not.

What am I missing here or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The val() function returns the value of the element which is '1'. You cannot use it to check the state of a checkbox. What you could do is to use the checked attribute, e.g.:

```
$('#chk').checked
```

which returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the checbox is checked or not. You can read more in the [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/prop/).